# Picking data from specific dates and not between them

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to use data from specific dates without the time (only year, day and month).
I found in the forum the way to choose between dates. How can I choose only 4 dates? Or maybe I have another problem?

The exclamation mark appears next to the fourth line:

```
CREATE TABLE
  `ecstatic-gantry-310013.BIG_DATA_2021.israel_media_person_election` AS
SELECT
  @FromDate ='20190409' or '20190917' or '20200302' or '20210406' ,
  person,
  COUNT(1) AS count_mentions,
FROM
  `ecstatic-gantry-310013.BIG_DATA_2021.israel_media_person`
GROUP BY
  person
ORDER BY
  count_mentions DESC
LIMIT
  50;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What is the "date" column in your table for instance?  What is `@FromDate`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff
The column's name is "date" and the type of the data is String. For example: 20160928081500 is actually 28/09/2016 at 15:00 o'clock.
'@FromDate' is from a tutorial that I found..
Thank you!

Comment: . . Your question needs *a lot* more explanation.  BigQuery has three data types for representing date/time values.  None of them are strings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This creates an aggregated answer by date and person (sorted by number
> of mentions):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `ecstatic-gantry-310013.BIG_DATA_2021.israel_media_person_election` AS
SELECT
  SUBSTR(CAST(date AS string), 1, 8) AS date,
  person,
  COUNT(1) AS count_mentions,
FROM
  `ecstatic-gantry-310013.BIG_DATA_2021.israel_media_person`
GROUP BY
  date,
  person
ORDER BY
  count_mentions DESC
LIMIT
  50;

Result looks like this (first 10 rows): 
date    person  count_mentions
20200412    Keenan Cohen    272
20200621    Yair Cadman     245
20191007    Yom Kippur  207
20200103    Qasem Soleimani     194
20190704    Reuben Castro   192
20191121    Benjamin Netanyahu  184
20200412    Reuben Castro   183
20171002    Las Vegas   180
20170714    Temple Mount    176
20210120    Joe Biden   170
```